# SVN checkout of multiple projects

Tags: svn

Let's say I have a fairly large repository containing a number of projects. I actually work on most of the projects. Should I have "one big working copy" locally that takes advanatage of the sparse directory feature to get what I need or should every project have its own working copy. What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the two largest factors that affect which approach to take are:

- Do all the projects share a large amount of library code?
- Are you working on the same branch for all projects?

If all the individual projects share a lot of library code and are considered to be part of the same software suite then it makes sense to have a single working copy as it minimises the amount of rebuilding and ensures that changes made in one project are visible in another (which minimises the chance of breaking the build).

On the other hand, if perhaps each of these projects is for a different client, and each one has a different timescale and needs to be done on a different branch (project A is in RC phase and requires only showstopper bug-fixes, project B is in alpha phase and can be heavily modified) then go for the separate sparse working copies approach.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same scenario. I checked out all of the projects in one structure instead of using sparse directories. Then it is very easy to update all the projects in one go, or just one project/folder at a time by just selection the desired folder and commit/update. That way you get the benifit of spase directory when you need it, or a complete update/commit instead of doing it one by one. My collection is about 5GB, 60k files, and both per project level or complete it is still very quick.

Answer (score 0):

One project each so that each commit (and rollback) is specific to that project. Also important if you plan to use capistrano or any other deploy tool. Also you restrict access per project.

Comment: you can still commit and rollback a partial checkout using a sparse working copy.

Answer (score 0):

As @the_mandrill said, it depends on whether your projects are part of a coherent whole as, for instance, jar files that are combined in a single Java EE web application.

In similar situations I use an umbrella project which holds overall build configuration, and pull in child projects by means of `svn::externals`. In the Java world this maps rather well with Maven based build practices, even though there are a few drawbacks.

I plan to try out a similar approach with Visual Studio projects and solutions, but I've only done simple experiments so far.